# How can I fix my iPad Magic Keyboard when everything works except the trackpad?

Tags: ipad, trackpad, ipados, magic-keyboard-ipad

I’ve got the Magic Keyboard (the one with the hinge that holds the iPad Pro suspended in air above the number keys) and everything works except the trackpad. I can go into the settings app General > Keyboard > Hardware Keyboard and the brightness reacts when I slide the control.

[image: Hardware Keyboard settings showing brightness control]

Note, on a rare occasion this is fixed by disconnecting everything for 20 seconds and reconnecting the USB C cable and then placing the iPad back in the keyboard, but often this issue persists and needs a power down.

What can be done to fix this so the trackpad works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a software issue and seldom a hardware issue. You can triage this by pairing a Bluetooth mouse and if it and then trackpad are broken, you can know it’s a software issue.

---

The first time this happened, Apple sent a replacement trackpad and while that was in transit, iOS  / iPadOS 13.5.1 (17F80) was released. Since the update, I have had no crashes of the `pointeruid` process, and also had the hardware  exchanged.

I also was able to attach a Bluetooth mouse and it fails to work when my magic device wasn’t working so I’m pretty sure the crashing process is the direct reason the pointer doesn’t draw on screen.

I have had their recur more often in the last 6 months. So far, it’s always been software, but I’m sure it can happen with hardware failure, but for me this is a software issue and restarting the iPad generally, but not always cures it.

---

Due to the timing, I believe it was software and not hardware, but I can't be sure. I would recommend contacting Apple Support if you can't check for crashes or still have issues with your device. I'll leave the rest of the initial troubleshooting below in case it helps others find their cursor on iPadOS.

In Xcode I see the process pointeruid crashing quite often. My working theory is that this crashes and if it doesn't restart, I lack a pointer and when I restarted the iPad, it was crashing before I could see the pointer ever draw.

```
Hardware Model:      iPad8,9
Process:             pointeruid [283]
Path:                /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PointerUIServices.framework/Support/pointeruid
Identifier:          pointeruid
Version:             ???
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Unspecified
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.apple.PointerUI.pointeruid [300]


Date/Time:           2020-05-28 11:17:52.8551 -0500
Launch Time:         2020-05-28 11:17:52.5865 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.5 (17F75)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000068
VM Region Info: 0x68 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4334665624
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 00000001025dc000-0000000102610000 [  208K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...rt/pointeruid

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [283]
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

---

Before calling Apple for support, here are the triage steps to self-rescue.

1. Power off the iPad while connected.
2. Disconnect power to the keyboard connector (left side on the bottom hinge)
3. Plug in USB C power - see the iPad power on - so I know the connection is solid
4. Update the iPad to iPadOS 13.5
5. Contact AppleCare. I’m received an engineering call back and they will ship a new keyboard to me so they can have this back. Not sure they will scrap it or analyze it, but for me I’ll wait for a second keyboard to test.

The triage steps I didn’t think of are as follows:

- open Accessability in general settings

When the keyboard is connected, you should see pointer control. Remove the iPad from the keyboard and the pointer option should vanish instantly. Reconnect and then make sure you turn off all the items: Automatically Hide, etc... and make the color / size large to be sure it’s not on screen and not visible.

[image: Pointer Control settings on iPadOS 13.5]

If your connectors are dirty, you won’t get the immediate change in pointer control. Also, inspect your keyboard closely under a brigh light for any hairline cracks or physical damage. If it got wet, that could cause the trackpad to fail.

Comment: My suspicions are hardware failure or a bug in the latest iOS - the trackpad has been super reliable until the last update - and it hasn’t worked once on 13.5 so I’m looking at that with cross eyes as well...

Comment: Too bad Apple has already stopped signing iPadOS 13.4.1.

Comment: Nah - I never go back, always forward for me. I did offer to install a beta iPadOS to test if they thought it could be software and Apple wanted to swap the part since it’s covered under warranty. I’ll report back in a couple days once a new keyboard is here.

Comment: I agree. No point in going backward for software. Please update once the replacement arrives. I am holding back from getting a new iPad Pro + Magic Keyboard setup for myself too, so I can certainly use some first hand feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are not alone. It appears to be a widely experienced issue. There's an extended discussion on the MacRumors forums at  [Magic keyboard trackpad stopped working](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/magic-keyboard-trackpad-stopped-working.2233242/).

Going through the discussion you'd see that there's no uniform approach that has resolved the issue. A variety of things have worked from cleaning the connectors, hard and soft restarting the iPad, reinstalling the iPadOS, etc. People appear to have experienced the issue with iPadOS 13.4.1 as well, so it could very well not just be a software issue.

It's not clear from the discussions if it's a hardware bug or a software bug. Also, the folks at Apple Support are apparently unprepared too with responses like "never heard before".

Contacting Apple support still is a good idea so they know how often this is happening and where / which OS.

Comment: No - don’t return it. Apple will fix any part that fails first year like this. Also, my experience is Apple is open with people if they see some cases - they are quite open in my experience with people needing help. My call was quick, effective and taught me things I didn’t think of to check. The iPad support app is awesome - text / quick / set up a follow on call with engineering, probably spent 20 minutes tops to test and arrange my swap.

Comment: So - Even though I didn’t want to return it, service sent me a swap. I worry it was software since the update fixed the crashing - I’ll never know if it was software or hardware now.. : - ( +1 for the help - sorry for forgetting to vote up before now

Comment: @bmike I agree. It would have been really helpful to know if it was hardware or software.

Comment: Good news is we now know exactly how to get at the crash logs.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem and was able to fix it like this:

1. Unplug the USB-C cable from the Magic Keyboard connector
2. Remove the iPad from the Magic Keyboard
3. Wait for about 10 seconds
4. Reconnect the USB-C cable to the Magic Keyboard
5. Attach the iPad to the Magic Keyboard

The trackpad should now work again. It might take a few seconds until the cursor actually appears again, so don't give up too soon if it doesn't work immediately.

I read large parts of the MacRumors forum thread that [this other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392409/26515) links to. But contrary to what's stated there, a lot of people in that thread report that the solution described above worked for them. It worked for me, too. So my impression is that it's the best shot at fixing this annoying problem.

Comment: I very much appreciate this answer. On rare occasions this is all that’s needed but if the process is crashing as I show in my answer, a reconnect won’t work and you need to power cycle the OS and hope the process doesn’t crash right away. The key is seeing the pointer change when you connect and disconnect in accessibility to know the process is healthy and detects the hardware connection.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like this easy method helped lots of people with this problem so I hope more will benefit from highlighting it a bit. Of course I totally acknowledge that it might not always solve the problem and appreciate your deeper analysis. It's really a bit of a shame that this seems to happen quite often in what's supposed to be some of Apple's top tier products and apparently haven't been properly addressed by them in years :-/

Comment: It comes and goes and I do +1 your help here.